# Highcharts: line graph with many datapoints

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am trying to generate a wind line graph, that shows wind gust and average speed for the last 24 hours, with 60 second intervals.
[image: Wind speed graph]

The data comes in every 60 seconds, as you can see the lines are choppy.
I tried using the spline function but it does not help, it only makes the lines a bit thicker.
How to fix this?
Also the band text is behind the graph, when it should be in front, any ideas?

```
$('#wind').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Wind - Last 24 hours'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
    credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                    enabled: true
            },
            tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    hour: '%H',
                    day: '%H'
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'Wind speed (km/h)'
            },
            min: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
            alternateGridColor: null,
            plotBands: [{ // Light air
                from: 1,
                to: 5,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Light air',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Light breeze
                from: 6,
                to: 11,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Light breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Gentle breeze
                from: 12,
                to: 19,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Gentle breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Moderate breeze
                from: 20,
                to: 28,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Moderate breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Fresh breeze
                from: 29,
                to: 38,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Fresh breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Strong breeze
                from: 39,
                to: 49,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Strong breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // High wind
                from: 50,
                to: 61,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'High wind',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
    },{ // Gale
                from: 62,
                to: 74,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Gale',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                 }
            }]
        }],
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                lineWidth: 1
                },
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Wind Gust',
    data: concatenatedWindgust,
        },
    {
    name: 'Wind Average',
    data: concatenatedWindavg,
    }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post some code, like the initialization of  the chart

Comment: to get the band labels above the lines use zIndex property and set them more than 10

Comment: Mayve better will be using highstock which group data and chart will be more clearful \http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the zindex of your plot bands like this:

```
plotBands: [{ // Light air
            from: 1,
            to: 5,
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
            label: {
                text: 'Light air',
                style: {
                    color: '#606060'
                }
            },
            zIndex:99
        },
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotBands.zIndex

With regards to the look of the chart, I think you are trying to plot too many points. Minute resolution gives you 1440 points per 24 hours. If your chart is less that 1440 pixels wide, you will lose some points in the plot anyway.

I suggest you either:

1. Change to using 2 minute intervals.
2. Use highstock and show 12 hours with a slider to allow the user to scroll back in time.